# Retrieving Json data from Web service in multi-value autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, autocomplete

I am using `autocomplete` textbox and trying to retrieve data from web service asmx file. I am retrieving data but same data is being repeated. I am not sure what is going on. Here is my `aspx` file:

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Emp_Autocomplete.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Inherits="AutoCompleteText.Emp_Autocomplete" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
              $('#<%=txtManagerName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ManagerService.asmx/Get_Employees",
                        data: "{ 'Condition':'" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                               return {
                                    Name: data.d.Name,
                                    EmployeeID: data.d.EmployeeID,
                                    DOB: data.d.DOB,
                                    json: data
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#<%=txtManagerName.ClientID%>').val(ui.item.Name);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#<%=txtManagerName.ClientID%>').val(ui.item.Name);
                    return false;
                },
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
                .append("<a><bold>Name:" + item.Name + "</bold><br>EmployeeID: " + item.EmployeeID + "<br>DOB: " + item.DOB + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h3>Multival autocomplete</h3>
     <div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtManagerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <div>
        <div><b>Name:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        <div><b>EmployeeID:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeID" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        <div><b>DOB:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblDOB" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
     </div>
     </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the asmx file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AutoCompleteText
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ManagerService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public string Name;
            public string EmployeeID;
            public string DOB;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public Employee Get_Employees(string Condition)
        {
            Employee objEmployee = new Employee();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.DataConnection.MyConnection.StrConn))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SEL_Employee_Info", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@Condition", Condition);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    objEmployee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    objEmployee.EmployeeID = rdr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                    objEmployee.DOB = rdr["DOB"].ToString();
                }
                rdr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            return objEmployee;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added picture to display that when I type say 77, I should retrieving all employees with 77 in their DOB from stored proc

[image: storedproc results],

but I'm retrieving only last employee. I can't figure out why is that? [image: data retrieved]

Comment: So you want your textBox to deal with both alphabets and numeric values, right?

Comment: @Adeel I am retrieving values correctly as I can loop thru the recordset. but only last record is displayed multiple times. I tried to attach png file to show stored proc results and what is displayed but its seems it did not get uploaded.